# Master detail view routing with AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire

I have a view that contains a list of posts in an ng-repeat. When a user clicks on a post they get routed to a details page for the selected post.

I've setup some routing but I'm having issues figuring out what to do with the id parameter I have injected into my controller to make the detail view load the correct post.

I'm also unsure if I'm passing the right value as the identifier for the post. The posts are stored as an array in Firebase and I'm not sure if I need to do something when the data is read in to store the FIrebase id. There is no explicit unique identifier within the data I load.

Post list view:

```
<div id='posts' ng-controller="PostsCtrl">

      <ul>
          <div id='post' ng-repeat="post in posts track by $id($index)">
              <div id='postMedia'>
              <img id='media' ng-click="go('/post/{{$id}}')" ng-src=   {{post.attachment}} />
              </div>
              <div id="articleRight">
                  <div ng-click="go('/post')">{{post.message}}</div>
```

Post controller:

```
myApp.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, angularFire, $routeParams) {
var url = 'https://inviter-dev.firebaseio.com/posts';
$scope.items = angularFire(url, $scope, 'posts',  [] );
$scope.currentPost = $scope.items[$routeParams.postid]
```

Post details view:

```
 <div class="container">

      <h1>{{$scope.$currentPost.message}}</h1>

      <ul>

              <div id='postMedia'>
              <img ng-click="" ng-src={{post.attachment}} />
              </div>
              <div ng-click="">
                  <div ng-click="">{{posts[$route.current.params.postid].message}}</div>
```

Routing:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/post/:postid', {
    templateUrl:'partials/post.html',
    authRequired: true,
    controller:'PostsCtrl'
})
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: I don't know how to make the subview bind to the selected post.

Comment: Here's a debugging pointer that should help get you started. Inspect your $scope.items object to determine how it is indexed (by id? by number?). Then inspect the variable you are trying to use as an index (in your case, $id). You should find that they don't match ($id will be something like 001, 002, etc., while $scope.items is probably indexed 0, 1, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I switched back to a dictionary because I think the AngularFire patch I refer to only works with dictionary. I did indeed inspect the items to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

This was tougher than I expected but an all night session solved it.

There is a fork of AngularFire which you need to access Firebase objects by their unique key generated by Firebase. I copied this version of AngularFire.js into my project. However, I found that it was missing AngularFIreAuth from the official 0.3 version so I added it to this and created the Gist below for the version I'm running. Hopefully, there will be a new official version soon -

Fork with fixes for accessing objects by key:
https://github.com/jeffreywescott/angularFire/blob/9aadb24e345e804ed31695787dd8f2360e8efdf2/angularFire.js

My version of AngularFire.js:
https://gist.github.com/wisemanIV/6275080

The master view needs to use the ng-repeat key, value syntax -

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">

      <ul>
          <div id='post' ng-repeat="(key, post) in posts">
              <div id='postMedia'>
              <img id='media' ng-click="go('post/{{key}}')" ng-src={{post.attachment}} />
              </div>
              <div id="articleRight" ng-click="go('/post')">
                  <div ng-click="go('/post')">{{post.message}}</div>
```

The routing looks like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/post/:postid', {
    templateUrl:'partials/post.html',
    authRequired: true,
    controller:'PostsCtrl'
})
```

This is the controller:

```
myApp.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, angularFire, $routeParams) {
var url = 'https://inviter-dev.firebaseio.com/posts';
$scope.items = angularFire(url, $scope, 'posts',  {} );

$scope.selectedItem = $routeParams.postid ;


$scope.getPost = function() {

     return $scope.posts[$scope.selectedItem]
}
```

This is the detail view:

```
 <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl" ng-init="post=getPost()">

      <ul>

              <div id='postMedia'>
              <img ng-click="" ng-src={{post.attachment}} />
              </div>
              <div ng-click="">
                  <div ng-click="">{{post.message}}</div>
                  <div ng-click="">{{post.created_at|since}}</div>
                  <div ng-click="">{{post.submitter}}</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome, I'll look into integrating "get object by unique ID" fix into the official version on AngularFire. Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of $scope.items in the controller?  I don't see it referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I used the $.on method to listen for the data being loaded inside the controller.  After that, just assigned a new scope variable to the specific article (post/item) I wanted to show the details of.

```
$scope.articles = $firebase(ref);

$scope.articles.$on("loaded", function() {
  $scope.article = $scope.articles[$routeParams.article_id];
});

$scope.articles.$on("change", function() {
  $scope.article = $scope.articles[$routeParams.article_id];
});
```

The 'change' section is needed if you make and updates to an item in detail view. This will sync up the list portion correctly.